# Scipy Sparse: Unexpected Identity Behavior

Tags: python, scipy

Following is my attempt to create a sparse matrix that has `c` as its diagonal. I know there is also alternative methods for this, but I'm rather curious why the following code is not working as expected:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse

c = np.arange(0,5)
>>> np.identity(5)*c
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.]])
>>> sparse.identity(5)*c
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
#expected output:
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 5 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
# and (sparse.identity(5)*c).todense() == np.identity(5)*c
```

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `sparse.identity(5)*c`, the multiplication operator of the sparse matrix is used, which is the algebraic matrix multiplication (i.e. a matrix times a vector gives a vector).

You can create a sparse diagonal matrix with a given diagonal using [`scipy.sparse.diags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html):

```
In [18]: from scipy import sparse

In [19]: c = np.arange(5)

In [20]: d = sparse.diags(c, 0)

In [21]: d
Out[21]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>

In [22]: d.A
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  4.]])
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this operator is being used? What is the reasoning behind that, and what are use cases? This is the emphasis behind my question, to understand the logic behind *why* it works the way it does.

Comment: I don't know what else to say except that the scipy sparse classes are *matrix* classes (not numpy arrays), and the original authors of the sparse matrix code chose to implement `*` as algebraic matrix multiplication.  That's not unreasonable--just don't think of them as sparse numpy arrays.  Numpy also has a (dense) matrix class (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), and that class also defines `*` as algebraic matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 common types of array multiplication, element-by-element, and matrix.

In MATLAB, `*` is the matrix version, `.*` is the element by element one.

In numpy, `*` is element by element (with broadcasting), 'np.dot' is the basic form of matrix multiplication.  Python developers have approved `@` as an operator that could be used for matrix multiplication (eventually).

For numpy `matrix` subclass, `*` is the matrix multiplication, `np.multiply` is used for element-by-element.  (`np.multiply` also works for `ndarray`.)

`scipy` follows the `np.matrix` convention.  `*` is the matrix multiplication.  `sparse.identity(5).multiply(c)` does the element by element multiplication (though it returns a `np.matrix`, not a sparse one).

As to why, it comes down to conventions that the developers were used to.  For linear algebra problems, matrix multiplication is common, hence it's use in `sparse`.  `np.matrix` copies the MATLAB conventions.  MATLAB was created to give access to FORTRAN matrix libraries.

In physics there's another convention, Einstein notation.  This is a generalized matrix multiplication, extended to more dimensions. `np.einsum` does this. It can implement element by element multiplication, though at its core it uses a 'sum of products' method.  But it's not been implemented for `np.matrix` or `sparse` (and really isn't needed since those are always 2d).

Notice how similar the specifications are for your example

```
np.einsum('ij,j->ij',np.identity(5),c) # element by element
np.einsum('ij,j->i',np.identity(5),c)  # matrix (sum on j)
```